# Removing WooCommerce Product Gallery from specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am setting up a specific template for a product category in WooCommerce. However, I'd like to remove product gallery. Here is how I'm setting it up:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'setup_my_product_category');

function setup_my_product_category(){
  $id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
  if( !isset( $id ) ) return;

  if ( class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term')) {
    $primary_term = yoast_get_primary_term_id( 'product_cat', $id );
    $term = get_term( $primary_term );

    $slug = $term->slug;

    if ($slug == 'my-product-category' ){
      disable_fields_my_category();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function disable_fields_my_category(){
  remove_post_type_support( 'product', 'custom-fields' );
  remove_post_type_support( 'product', 'comments' );
  remove_post_type_support( 'product', 'author' );

  remove_meta_box( 'woocommerce-product-images',  'product', 'side');
}
```

I'm pretty sure woocommerce-product-images is the name of the meta box. However, in this context, the meta box is not removed. I only need it removed for this product category as it doesn't use the gallery to begin with. Do I need to call it in a different context?